# atoi() not working as expected

Tags: c++, std, atoi

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
•
• //main func declaration etc...
•
//Vectors for storing information from file
vector<string> include;
vector<string> exclude;
string temp; //for storing whatever the stream is on
int len = atoi(puzzle_file >> temp); //first pos
int width = atoi(puzzle_file >> temp); //second pos
```

The above code is supposed to read in a file and store the numbers in the corresponding ints. I'm getting an error that says "no matching function for call to 'atoi'", even though I have #include <\cstdlib> and #include <\stdlib.h> in my file header. Unsure of where to go from here. Did some research on stackoverflow and other forums, couldn't find anything that really helped me out. Any advice? Thanks

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: `c_str()` is the way to go..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`puzzle_file >> temp` expression returns `istream`, but there is no `atoi` overload that would accept such a parameter.

You should call `atoi(temp.c_str());`

Answer (score 1):

You should use [stoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) instead of [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/).

`stoi` takes a `std::string` as parameter while `atoi` takes `const char*` as parameter.

And don't forget `stoi` is new since c++11.

Comment: For my class it's not recommended we use C++11 because the hw submission server isn't fully compatible with it. Regardless, when I tried using stoi it still gave me the error "no matching function for call to 'stoi'". Am I calling the function incorrectly or am I just forgetting an #include statement?

Comment: It shouldn't happen I think, how about posting more of your code here?@ThunderBow98

Comment: The formatting is horrible for comments so just check the OP, sorry about that and thanks

Answer (score 0):

You tried to skip one instruction and lost. `puzzle_file >> temp` returns `puzzle_file` and not `temp`. So you apply `atoi` to an input stream which is converted to a bool. Use:

```
int len, width;
puzzle_file >> len >> width;
if (! puzzle_file)...
```